# I'd like to return this: {'Feature_Name[value]': {'MY_username':'value','started_my_time':'value'} in python3.5

Tags: python-3.5

Below code i have used but not getting correct output.

```
def seek_keys(d, key_list):
    newdict1 =   dict([(vkey, vdata) for vkey, vdata in d.items() if(vdata) ])
    dict1={}
    for kk,vv in newdict1.items():
        if kk in key_list:
            dict1[kk]=[]
            dict1[kk].append(vv)
            print(dict1)                
        if isinstance(newdict1[kk], dict):
            seek_keys(newdict1[kk], key_list)

filtered_list4 = ['Feature_Name', 'MY_username', 'started_my_time']

seek_keys(converted_xml,filtered_list4)
```

I'd like to return this:

```
{'Feature_Name[value]': {'MY_username':'value','started_my_time':'value'}
```

This is the dictionary i am using-

```
my_dict ={'1': {'Feature_Name': 'Lucky', 'usage_details_for_KD': 'No user details available_bye', 'use_percentage_file': '0%'}, '2': {'Feature_Name': 'Kunal', 'usage_details_for_KD': {'usage_details_for_KD_values': {'1': {'MY_description': 'for ' 'USER', 'started_my_time': '', 'MY_username': '1'}}}}, '3': {'Feature_Name': 'KD_M', 'usage_details_for_KD': {'usage_details_for_KD_values': {'1': {'MY_description': 'KD_DISPLAY ' '(0001)', 'started_my_time': 'Mon 12/23 ' '11:11', 'MY_username': 'KD_SI'}, '2': {'MY_description': 'Hello ' '0001)', 'started_my_time': 'Mon 12/23 ' '12:06', 'MY_username': 'Real_hero'}}}}, '4': {'Feature_Name': 'MY_NAME', 'usage_details_for_KD': {'usage_details_for_KD_values': {'1': {'MY_description': 'KD_DISPLAY ' '0001)',
'started_my_time': 'Mon 12/23 ' '13:57', 'MY_username': 'Same_hero'}}}}, '5': {'Feature_Name': 'Your_NAME', 'usage_details_for_KD': 'No user details available_bye', 'use_percentage_file': '0%'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Issue has been resolved, as i manage to solve.

class CoinBuilder_for_user_details:
  def __init__(self,dict1,dict2):
        self.Feature = dict2['Feature']
        self.MY_username = dict1['MY_username']
        self.started_my_time = dict1['started_my_time']

def main ():
    max_key_all_f=max(converted_xml['Usages'])
    for i in range(1,max_key_all_f+1):
        if(ign not in converted_xml['Usages'][i]['usage_details_for_KD']):
            print("\nFinal output is ")
            max_key_user =(max(converted_xml['Usages'][i]['usage_details_for_KD']['usage_details_for_KD_values']))
            if(type(max_key_user) == str):
                A1=CoinBuilder_for_user_details(converted_xml['Usages'][i]['usage_details_for_KD']['usage_details_for_KD_values'],converted_xml['Usages'][i])
                if(A1.statred not in null_v):
                        print("Feature Name : ",A1.Feature)
                        print("My User Name : ",A1.MY_username)
                        print("Date : ",A1.started_my_time)`enter code here`
```